# Получить 'href' значение в selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, href

Всем привет! Пишу программу и столкнулся с проблемой. Облазил везде чтобы решить ее, но так и не понял как правильно получить значение 'href' в Selenium. Если что мне надо несколько таких же кодов спарсить с одной страницы.

**Вот фрагмент кода страницы который нужно спарсить:**

```
<div class="r">

   <a href="ссылка">
```

А вот код который я написал в python:

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"href")]')

print(posts)
```

Выбивает ошибку. В основном из-за - list. Но я уже пытался писать

```
for post in posts:
   print(posts)
```

Все равно не помогает. Хочу увидеть что вы думаете

Спасибо!

Comment: Какую ошибку-то? Ну и если внутри значения атрибута href не содержится слово href, то такой селектор очевидно ничего не найдёт

Comment: В начале про list (уже не помню как именно оно писало) но я понял эту ошибку так как у меня несколько href сыллок (5+) и вроде исправил, а сейчас про - 'method' is not subscriptible'. В общем не знаю что делать

Comment: В какой строке-то?

Comment: В общем у меня получилось исправить ошибку вот таким вот способом  - posts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".r [href]")   links = [post.get_attribute('href') for post in posts] print(links)